# WP User Frontend Action Hook using post_title

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the Wordpress plugin WP User Frontend. I have a POST form setup that creates a post in a custom post type. I want that same post when setup to create another post in another custom post type. For this secondary post, I want to use the `post_title` as it's title.

I have:

```
add_action('create_whiteboard_hook', 'create_whiteboard', 10, 3 );
function create_whiteboard( $form_id, $post_id, $form_settings ) {
    $post_id = wp_insert_post(array (
        'post_type' => 'whiteboard',
        'post_title' => $_POST['post_title'],
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'comment_status' => 'closed',
        'ping_status' => 'closed',
    ));
}
```

This works OK (as in it does create an additional post on the whiteboard (custom post type)) but it comes through with a title of (no title). I can manually set the title but I want it to automatically get it from the title the user puts in...